# How to convert MultipartFile( image ) to DataSource object

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Java Spring MVC web application.

In my Controller, I am getting a image that comes from a form as MultipartFile.
I need convert this MultipartFile to a javax.activation.DataSource.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
// add attachment to multipart content
        MimeBodyPart attPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        FileDataSource ds = new FileDataSource(fileName);
        attPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
        attPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
        attPart.setFileName(ds.getName());
```